# Filter a string array from string array in an object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an array of string: `string[] sourceDestinationValue`. There's another object: `XRefResponse mappedValuesResponse`. The properties of the object are mentioned below:

```
    public string[] SourceValuesField;

    public string[] MappedValuesField;

    public bool AllValuesMappedField;

    public string[] CommentField;
```

I want to filter SourceValuesField property of XRefResponse class based upon sourceDestinationValue
and return an array of MappedValuesField property for matched values using Linq.

I have tried this:

```
var result = sourceDestinationValue.Where(x => mappedValuesResponse.SourceValues.Any(s => s.Contains(x))).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you have a class like this one:

```
class XRefResponse
{
    public string[] SourceValuesField;
    public string[] MappedValuesField;
    public bool AllValuesMappedField;
    public string[] CommentField;
}
```

And a variable like this one:

```
XRefResponse mappedValuesResponse
```

You want to use Linq (I don't see any EntityFramework specialized code in your sample) to get all values of MappedValuesField whose positions match the values of SourceValuesField that are found in a given array.

Based on that, I assume that `SourceValuesField` and `MappedValuesField` are both non-null and have the same length.

Then, a possible solution can be:

```
string[] Filter(XRefResponse mappedValuesResponse, string[] sourceDestinationValue)
    {
        var allPairs = mappedValuesResponse.SourceValuesField.Zip(mappedValuesResponse.MappedValuesField, (source, mapped) => new { Source = source, Mapped = mapped });
        var matchedPairs = allPairs.Where(pair => Array.IndexOf(sourceDestinationValue, pair.Source) >= 0);
        var result = matchedPairs.Select(pair => pair.Mapped);
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

This method does the following things:

1. Creates a sequence of pairs from values of `SourceValueField` and `MappedValuesField` (see [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) method).
2. Filters all the pairs where the `Source` field matches any of the `sourceDestinationValue` values.
3. Returns a new sequence that contains only the `Mapped` values from the previous step.

Local variables help understanding the code and separating sub-operations, but you can remove them if you like.

In case `SourceValueField` and `MappedValuesField` are always handled in pairs, a better implementation could be having a single array containing values from both fields (maybe using Tuples, e.g.: `public Tuple<string,string>[] ValuesField;`) or a dictionary where the keys correspond to `SourceValueField` and the values correspond to `MappedValuesField` (e.g.: `public Dictionary<string,string> ValuesField;`).